# compare two IP address using bc

Tags: shell-script, scripting, bc, ip-address

I am trying to compare two IP address using bc command however the IP with lower numeric value is not being trapped in the test.

Here is my code:

```
TEST=$(echo "$i < $IP_BRD && $i > $IP_LOW " | bc -q )
```

If `TEST` results to 1, the process continues else exits.

check the below example:

```
++ echo '191.35 < 187.254 && 191.35 > 184.1 '
+ TEST=0
++ echo '191.35 < 191.254 && 191.35 > 188.1 '
++ bc -q
+ TEST2=0
++ echo '191.35 < 195.254 && 191.35 > 192.1 '
++ bc -q
+ TEST3=0
+ [[ 0 = 1 ]]
+ [[ 0 = 1 ]]
+ [[ 0 = 1 ]]
```

In line `echo '191.35 < 191.254 && 191.35 > 188.1 '` the IP 191.35 is less than 191.254 however its not being seen as it.

I have tried double quoutes in the `TEST=$(echo "$i < $IP_BRD && $i > $IP_LOW " | bc -q )` however didnt had much success.

Any ideas how to fix it ?

Comment: Relating [bc's POSIX spec does not require bare conditionals](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/bc.html)

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> In line echo '191.35 < 191.254 && 191.35 > 188.1 ' the IP 191.35 is less than 191.254 however its not being seen as it.

No, it's not: 191.35 == 191.350 > 191.254. bc compares them numerically, it can't compare IPs directly. You should convert the IP to integer first. Then you can compare them using shell built-ins without resorting to external tools.

Edit: check out this thread: [IP Address Converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768160/ip-address-converter)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a GNU toolchain you can identify the lowest of a set of values with `sort`. This can also handle partial IP addresses like the `191.35` and `187.254` in your example.

```
printf "%s\0" 191.35 187.254 | sort -zV | head -zn 1 | tr -d '\0'
```

Drop this into a shell function and you can then use equality testing to identify the lower of two IP addresses:

```
# Return the lowest of a set of IP addresses
lowIP() {
    printf "%s\0" "$@" | sort -zV | head -zn 1 | tr '\0' '\n'
}

# Sample session
try=191.35
if [[ $(lowIP "$try" 187.254) == "$try" ]]
then
    echo "$try is the lower value"
else
    echo "$try is not the lower value"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `bc` here; your shell can handle the octets of an IPv4 address:

```
(
  IFS=.
  read i1 i2 i3 i4 <<< "$i"
  read b1 b2 b3 b4 <<< "$IP_BRD"
  read l1 l2 l3 l4 <<< "$IP_LOW"
  if [ "$i1" -le "$b1" -a "$i2" -le "$b2" -a "$i3" -le "$b3" -a "$i4" -lt "$b4" ] &&
    [ "$l1" -le "$i1" -a "$l2" -le "$i2" -a "$l3" -le "$i3" -a "$l4" -lt "$i4" ]
  then
    echo success
  else
    echo failure
  fi
)
```

If you *really* want to use `bc` just to compare digits, then generate a large `if` statement of the form:

```
if (a < b)
  if (c < d)
    # ...
      1
```

namely:

```
if [ "$(printf "if (%d <= %d) if (%d <= %d) if (%d <= %d) if (%d < %d) \n \
                if (%d <= %d) if (%d <= %d) if (%d <= %d) if (%d < %d) 1\n" \
        "$i1" "$b1" "$i2" "$b2" "$i3" "$b3" "$i4" "$b4" \
        "$l1" "$i1" "$l2" "$i2" "$l3" "$i3" "$l4" "$i4" | bc)" = 1 ]
then
  echo success
else
  echo failure
fi
```